# Find the general solution of $y'= a^{x + y}$ where y is the function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How should I approach this problem? Should I put ln logarithm on both sides and move factor of variable of lnx on right side in front of the ln, or do somehing else? I understand general solving and types of solving these differential equations of first order, but I have no idea what my next step should be.

Answer (score 2):

Given is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=a^{x+y}$$
Now, when multiplying by $dxa^{-y}$, we get
$$a^{-y}dy=a^xdx$$
Taking the integral on both sides
$$\int a^{-y}dy=\int a^xdx$$
And so, for any fixed $C\in\mathbb{R}$, $$-\frac{1}{\log(a)}a^{-y}=\frac{1}{\log(a)}a^x+C$$
which we can write to $$a^y=-\frac{1}{a^{x}+C\log(a)}$$
And so we get $$y=\log_a\left(-\frac{1}{a^{x}+C\log(a)}\right)$$
Since $\log(a)$ can take any value, we can replace $C'=-C\log(a)$ with $C'\in\mathbb{R}$, and rewrite this to $$y=\log_a\left((C'-a^x)^{-1}\right)$$
therefore
$$y=-\log_a(C'-a^x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{-y}\cdot y' = a^x \implies -\ln (a)\cdot a^{-y}\cdot y' = -\ln (a)\cdot a^x$$
Notice that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(a^{-y}\right) = -\ln(a)a^{-y}\frac d{dx}y$$
So...
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(a^{-y}\right) = -\ln(a)a^x \implies \dots$$